# Handling elementary but messy computations in proofs

Tags: soft-question, problem-solving, education, symbolic-computation

Often when working on a proof, I get to a computation which appears to be elementary (e.g. requiring only standard algebra and perhaps calculus) but messy.  Solving this via pen and paper is tedious and error prone, yet the path to a solution is not always elegant (or, at the least, an elegant path is not always apparent to this amateur mathematician).

How would you advise a beginning mathmeatician to handle these cases? How do seasoned mathematicians handle this?  Often I proceed forwards with pen and paper, but more often than not this results in elementary errors (sometimes simply because the amount of writing gets huge, my penmanship gets sloppy, and I misread my writing).  Should I simply be more patient and explicit, and learn to do these computations by hand, accurately if laboriously?  Should I learn to use software such as Sage to do them? Or should I take the computational ugliness as a sign that a more elegant proof should be approached?

## Update

A good example of the algebraic manipulations I'm talking about are those referenced (but not spelled out) in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/246288/

Comment: @Righter The algebraic manipulations used for the induction in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098161/prove-midpoint-sequence-converges-to-endpoint

Comment: I used to have spiral notebooks with hand-written polynomial and trig equations of many hundreds of terms. Manually manipulating them was nicely meditative, and it honed my intuition about seeing patterns, anticipating factors, internalizing trig identities, etc. These days, a computer algebra system makes light work of equations with many hundreds *of thousands* of terms. *These days are better.* :) ... Brute-force symbol-bashing with a CAS can help to identify a solution to a problem quickly; once the solution is known, finding the *elegant* path to it is often easier.

Comment: There's not a single right answer. Sometimes you do messy calculations and later discover another viewpoint that obviates them. Sometimes you don't find a way to simplify, but can't be certain such a simplification is impossible. Symbolic software can help, especially in the exploration/discovery phase. I personally prefer pen and paper. There have been times where (with expressions stretching over three lines when writing in landscape mode on letter paper) I had to do a calculation multiple times, and only feel confident when it came out the same three times in a row.

Comment: "Beginning mathematician" is a little vague here, and I think the context matters. For instance, are you still a student/would you ever be judged in the future on ability to handwrite a calculation you couldn't memorize or use a reference/calculator for? Are you no longer a student but working in a subfield of math where you often have to face calculations beyond the abilities of your favorite CAS (so that keeping your skills up and growing your intuition for calculations is important)? Etc.

Comment: @MarkS. I am long past school and studying mathematics as an avocation.  I work in software by day where math is useful but not the bread and butter.

Comment: I'm not a "seasoned mathematician", but a lot of times if I'm trying to prove something, I plug in expressions on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), then simplify step by step. I can see if I mess up somewhere if the value changes. There's a couple of drawbacks to this though - I have to specify some values (e.g. the value of $n$ in the linked answer) and I can't use complex numbers. For more advanced problems, I do a similar thing in Mathematica. But the drawback to Mathematica is a) the display isn't as nice and b) you have to learn at least basic commands.

Comment: It is a good idea to carefully document as much of the solving process as possible, e.g. in hand written or typed up notes including any numerical code or software syntax used. In the main body of text in a professional paper, generally not every single fine detail needs to be spelled out and can instead be left to an appendix or supplemental resource. It will depend on the target journal and audience too, and author/editor/reviewer subjective preference. There is no universal rule on this, but generally enough detail should be shown that a seasoned reader in the discipline will follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the context and the goal.

If your goal is just to *find* answers and verify a result, then by all means use a [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) to do the algebra for you. (For example, some computation-heavy papers just say things like "by SAGE, the answer for this is step is...". But if you want to keep your algebra skills sharp, then maybe just use a computer to check your error-prone steps.

And if you want to learn more mathematics, maybe search out/ask people for relevant generalizations.

For example, if I weren't teaching someone induction, I would never write out the induction for the formula for $J_n$ alluded to in the post you linked, because I know a general theorem about [homogenous linear recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients). With that theorem in hand, it suffices to check $J_1$, $J_2$, and to solve $r^2=r+2$.

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> Often when working on a proof, I get to a computation which appears to be elementary (e.g. requiring only standard algebra and perhaps calculus) but messy. Solving this via pen and paper is tedious and error prone, yet the path to a solution is not always elegant (or, at the least, an elegant path is not always apparent to this amateur mathematician).

> How would you advise a beginning mathematician to handle these cases?

My advice is that if you solving algebra/calculus problems, then a CAS can be
a very valuable tool for a few reasons.

One reason you mentioned is "tedious" calculations. It can be much faster and
less error-prone for even a simple calculator to do some of the calculations.
The more capable the CAS, the better it is able to handle the task required.

Another reason is to check your arithmetic and algebraic equations no matter how
they are derived. It is very  easy to make sign errors, copy errors, and other
kind of errors. We all make these mistakes, but a CAS can check for many of these
errors. For example, if an equation is supposed to be true for all $\,x\,$, then
you can use a CAS to test this for many numerical values of $\,x\,$

Yet another reason is that many CAS can perform operations that are not possible
to do by manual methods. For example, factoring multi-variable polynomials is
almost impossible with manual methods, yet is a standard capability of many CAS.
This can lead to elegant proofs if you can find significant factors of a rational
function. For example, suppose that $\,a,b,c\,$ are three angles such that
$\,a+b+c=2\pi.\,$ Then they satisfy the equation
$$\cos(a)^2+\cos(b)^2+\cos(c)^2-2\cos(a)\cos(b)\cos(c)-1=0.$$ This can be proved
by setting $\,a=(\log A)/i,b=(\log B)/i,c=(\log C)/i.\,$ Substituting into the
left side of the equation and factoring reveals a factor of $\,1-ABC\,$ which
translates into the result that $\,a+b+c\,$ is a multiple of $\,2\pi.$ Note that
in this example $\,a,b,c\,$ are the angle measures of the three sides of a spherical triangle which lies in a plane.